# Integration test with WebApplicationFactory fails with ObjectDisposedException for IServiceProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, integration-testing, xunit

I have a simple health check test which looks like this:

```
public class HealthCheckEndpointTests : IClassFixture<ItemsApplicationFactory>
{
    private readonly ItemsApplicationFactory _factory;

    public HealthCheckEndpointTests(ItemsApplicationFactory factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    public async Task HealthCheck_Test()
    {
       // Arrange
       HttpClient httpClient = _factory.CreateClient();

       // Act 
       string response = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("/health/live");

       // Assert
       Assert.Equal("Healthy", response);
    }
}
```

My ItemsApplicationFactory looks like this:

```
public class ItemsApplicationFactory : WebApplicationFactory<Program>
{
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureKestrel(options => options.AllowSynchronousIO = true);


        builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            // remove db context options if exists 
            var dbContextDescriptor = services.SingleOrDefault(d => d.ServiceType == typeof(DbContextOptions<ItemsDbContext>));
            if (dbContextDescriptor != null)
                services.Remove(dbContextDescriptor);

            var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection()
                .AddEntityFrameworkInMemoryDatabase()
                .BuildServiceProvider();

            services.AddDbContext<ItemsDbContext>(mariaDb =>
            {
                mariaDb.UseInMemoryDatabase("template");
                mariaDb.UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceCollection);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

When I run the test, I get the following exception thrown

```
System.ObjectDisposedException : Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'IServiceProvider'
```

I have changed my test, to see if the exception is caused by initialization of ItemsApplicationFactory or HttpClient. So the test looks like this

```
public class HealthCheckEndpointTests : IClassFixture<ItemsApplicationFactory>
{
    private readonly ItemsApplicationFactory _factory;

    public HealthCheckEndpointTests(ItemsApplicationFactory factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    public async Task HealthCheck_Test()
    {
       // Arrange
       HttpClient httpClient = _factory.CreateClient();

       // Act 
       await Task.Completed();

       // Assert
       Assert.True(true);
    }
}
```

The test did not throw any exception.

Why `_factory.CreateClient();` does not throw, but `httpClient.GetStringAsync("/health/live")` does? And how to fix that?

Comment: Could you please share details of your exception? What error you are getting?

Comment: Can't find `Task.Completed();`

Comment: you can put a try/catch clause in your Program, so that you can debug and find out the issue, it worked for me.